# Exportar excel como Hoja de cálculo xml 2003 con epplus

Tags: c#, xml, windows-forms, excel, epplus

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual genero varios documentos excel con información, la cual luego debe ser Importada en un software de gestión.

El problema, es que el software de gestión lee documentos excel guardados como 'Hoja de cálculo xml 2003'.

Intenté guardar el documento como xml con esperanza de que lo reconozca pero no fue el caso.

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "CodigoInteligente", "Articulos.xml");
var archivo = new FileInfo(path);
```

Me gustaría evitar usar Microsoft Interop, para no necesitar obligadamente excel instalado en la pc de trabajo.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo encarar este problema?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo temporalmente con `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, sigo en búsqueda de una mejor solución, pero lo dejo como una respuesta porque quizás a alguien pueda serle de ayuda en un futuro.

Tener en cuenta que **REQUIERE EXCEL** instalado en la pc

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = null;
bool status = false;
try 
    { 
    var originalPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "CodigoInteligente" , "Originales" , "Articulos.xls");
    var oldFile = new FileInfo(originalPath);
    if (!oldFile.Exists)
        {
            return false;
        }
    var newPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "CodigoInteligente", "Articulos.xls");
    var newFile = new FileInfo(newPath);
    if (newFile.Exists)
        {
        if (IsFileLocked(newFile))
            {
                return false;
            }
        newFile.Delete();
        }
    book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(originalPath);
    book.SaveAs(newPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet);
    status = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hubo un error");
        Logs.agregarLog(ex);
        return false;
    }
    finally
        {                
        book.Close(false);
        xlApp.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
return status;
```